# Need help with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two classes that looks as follows:

```
public class Rule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public RuleGroup RuleGroup { get; set; }
}


public class RuleGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Rule> RuleList { get; set; }
}
```

A RuleGroup has a list of rules. My AutoMapper settings are as follows:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<RuleRecord, FirstSolar.Mes.Core.Entities.Recipe.Rule>()
   .ForMember(destination => destination.RuleGroup, source => source.Ignore())
   .ForMember(destination => destination.Id, source => source.MapFrom(item => item.RuleId));
Mapper.CreateMap<IList<RuleRecord>, IList<FirstSolar.Mes.Core.Entities.Recipe.Rule>>();

Mapper.CreateMap<RuleGroupRecord, FirstSolar.Mes.Core.Entities.Recipe.RuleGroup>()
   .ForMember(destination => destination.Id, source => source.MapFrom(item => item.RuleGroupId));
Mapper.CreateMap<IList<RuleGroupRecord>, IList<FirstSolar.Mes.Core.Entities.Recipe.RuleGroup>>();
```

When I attempt to map a RuleGroupRecord (LinqToSQL object) to RuleGroup (DTO), AutoMapper says I need to add a mapping for RuleGroup.RuleList. I'm wondering why because I defined how to map a single RuleRecord and a List.

If I have to, how would I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add (I hope I got the syntax right, but you should see what I'm hinting at):

```
.ForMember(destination => destination.RuleList, source => source.MapFrom(item => item.Rules));
```

to the second mapping. While you handled the general mapping for `RuleRecord` to `Rule` in the first mapping, you didn't tell automapper to map the specific property `RuleGroup.RuleList`.

Comment: This replaces one error with another. I think the problem is due to the fact that, in your example, the source (item.Rules) is not the same type as the destination (destination.RuleList). The source is an EntitySet of entities (L2S) and the destination is my own DTO list. The exception I'm getting back from AutoMapper is just a general mapping exception. No detail on what the actual problem is.

Comment: Try removing the specific `IList` mappings. You don't need those anyway, and I think they are in fact breaking the mapping.